# LED dimmer not fading out

Tags: arduino-uno, led, loop

I'm trying to make an LED go from no brightness to max and back down on a loop and I've encountered a problem I can't seem to crack. The LED will go to maximum brightness steadily as it should but then it will drop to zero brightness and start again... Why?

```
int blue_led=10;

void setup() {  
  pinMode(blue_led,OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {

  int voltage=0;

  for(int i=0;i<=255;i+1){

    analogWrite(blue_led,voltage);
    voltage=voltage+1;
    delay(8);
  }
   int volts=255;

   for(int i=0;i<=255;i+1){

    analogWrite(blue_led,volts);
    volts=volts-1;
    delay(8);
   }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your for() loop should end with with either "i=i+1" or "i++" or "i +=1". In your code you are just saying i+1, which doesn't actually affect "i". So the first loop continues endlessly, and the "voltage" variable (which should not exceed 255) continues to go into the "illegal" range. The arduino likely translates the illegal values to 0. Eventually, since 'voltage' is just a 2 byte integer, it will finally become 0 again. This will happen in 65536 * 8ms, which should be about 8.7 minutes. But I don't think that's what you want. ;-)

Comment: `i` could be used instead of `voltage` and `volts`, couldn't it? I mean, is max voltage 255?

Comment: Sure, 'i' could be used, because 255 is indeed the maximum allowed value for the  PWM pins. But again, the 'i' in the OP's code will never go past '0', until the for() loop is fixed.

Here's a handy article about it...

https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/projects/using-the-arduinos-analog-io/

Comment: Ah i understand. I just made the changes and it works perfectly! Thanks so much!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, Randy. @ThisUsernameHasBeenTaken, if the answer solved your problem you can mark it as accepted (see [help center](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers))

Comment: Just done :) Thanks

Comment: Also note that using delay is generally a bad idea. (Your code freezes until the delay time passes, so your Arduino can't do anything else during that pause.) You should get used to writing code that records the current value of `millis()` and waits for it to increment to a desired end value. Do a Google search on "Arduino blink without delay" for an explanation of that.